# Redirect Lightbox after form submission

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fancybox-2

I'm using Fancybox 2 to display some forms on my website.  The form comes through from an external page into an IFrame to let the user post a message, kind of like twitter does.  However I want the user to be re-directed after the form has been posted. So they post the form to a database, the Fancybox window shuts down and then they are redirected to the posts page where they see their newly posted message. Is there a way of doing this succesfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    <script>
    if(data == 1){
        //window.location.replace("dashboard.php");   //will open the page in the fancybox
        parent.$.fancybox.close();                    //will close the fancybox 
        //parent.window.location.replace( your_url_here );              //your redirecting URL here
        parent.window.location.href =  'dashboard.php';              //your redirecting URL here
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this now redirects me to the form as a full page and does not submit the information to the database table

Comment: I've narrowed it down to: `if(data == 1){
    parent.$.fancybox.close();                    //will close the fancybox 
    window.location.replace("dashboard.php");            //your redirecting URL here
   }else{` and now it's entering the information into the database and closing the Fancybox, but it just won't replace the window?

Comment: No, it's still posting to the database, closing the box but the redirection isn't working at all?

Comment: have you used the "parent." syntax?

Comment: Okay use the commented ( href ) part now. and comment out the "replace" one. I have edited the code now. Please check your console for any error too.

Comment: No it's still not doing the redirect - Should your_url_here be "dashboard.php"?

Comment: yes, oh that means you were using the code just like as it is? Anyways try again with the above code.

Comment: Thanks, I've sorted it out and it turns out I didn't need the `parent.$.fancybox.close();` line at all, simply using `parent.window.location.href =  "dashboard.php" ;`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a real `form` rather than a `post` action. You are not really using form submission otherwise, but just a `POST` request.

If you do that, you could use the `target="_top"` inside the `<form` tag and submit the results using the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function of jQuery.

Comment: It still opens up the new target window inside the Fancybox IFrame

Comment: I should point out that the Fancybox form popup is from an external page

Comment: Try it then with `target="_parent"`